# Concatenate path and variable in C

Tags: c

This is my code. I need create 10 files with this format:

0.txt
1.txt
...

But I can't do it, the result is different. Can anyone help?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* direccion(char *dirD,int number){
    char buffer[100];
    char *n;
    char *q;
    char* formato=".txt";

    sprintf(buffer, "%i", number);
    n= strcat(dirD,buffer);
    q= strcat(n,formato);

    return q;

}
int main(){
    int u;
    int number= 0;
    int t= 0;
    char* q = "e:/c9/";
    for(t=0; t< 10 ; t++){

        char* dir = direccion(q,number);

            if(fopen(dir,"w")){
                fopen(dir,"w");
                u=1;
            }
            else{
                u=0;
                printf("Error\n");
            }
        number++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Is this under Windows at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem No 1. is:

```
char *q = "e:/c9/";
for(t = 0; t < 10; t++)
{
    char *dir = direccion(q, number);
}
```

The variable q is a string literal. However, in the function `direccion()`, you pass it as the first argument to `strcat()`, which tries to modify it — BOOM, a segfault. Solution:

```
char buf[1000];
strcpy(buf, "e:/c9/");
char *dir = direccion(buf, number);
```

Problem #2 is as @Charlie Martin pointed out is that you return a <s>statically</s> automatically allocated local string, which is invalid after the `direccion()` function returns. Maybe

```
return strdup(buffer);
```

in this case; don't forget to free it after use.

Edit: seems you don't even ask about this. You can create a file using the `open()` system call (function):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int fd = open("file.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
close(fd);
```

Of course substitute the actual file mode you want for 0644 (but don't make the file executable unless it contains a program to be executed).

Edit 2: I didn't even catch this one... So, in the for loop, you want to reset the base filename over and over:

```
for (yadda yadda)
{
    strcpy(buf, "e:/c9/");
    char *dir = direccion(buf, i);
}
```

etc.

Comment: Nice , but now the files created :
0.txt , 0.txt1.txt , 0.txt1.txt2.txt, etc, how can solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating the buffer in automatic inside your function, which means it's allocated on the stack.  When you return, that memory is no longer valid.  You want to allocate the buffer in the *caller* and pass a pointer to it, or allocate it as static.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a series of path handling functions that you can use to do things like add an extension to a path.
 For example:

```
PathAddExtension(buffer,".txt");
```

For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, it's a good idea to work with buffers of _MAX_PATH size when dealing with paths.